# How to check if can write to a folder

Tags: julia, file-permissions

In julia, how do I check if the current  is allowed to write to a folder?

I could do the python way, and just attempt to do it, and then fail fail and recover.
(In my case I can definitely recover, I have a list of locations to attempt to write to,  as fallbacks. I expect the first few not to work (The first few are shared locations, so only computer admins are likely to have permission to writer there)

Answer (score 4):

Python has also [os.access](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.access) function. Maybe Julia will have something similar in the future. Now we could borrow idea. :)

It is implemented in [posixmodule.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/posixmodule.c) (also functionality for windows!) so if you are on posix you could simply mimic:

```
julia> const R_OK = 4  # readability
julia> const W_OK = 2  # writability
julia> const X_OK = 1  # executability
julia> const F_OK = 4  # existence

julia> access(path, mode) = ccall(:access, Cint, (Cstring, Cint), path, mode) == 0;
```

Small test:

```
julia> access("/root", W_OK)
false

julia> access("/tmp", W_OK)
true
```

(for windows it could be just a little more complicated... But I could not test it now)

EDIT:

Thanks to Matt B. we could use libuv support in Julia which has to be portable (although slower on posix systems):

```
julia> function uv_access(path, mode)
    local ret
    req = Libc.malloc(Base._sizeof_uv_fs)
    try
        ret = ccall(:uv_fs_access, Int32, (Ptr{Void}, Ptr{Void}, Cstring, Int64, Ptr{Void}), Base.eventloop(), req, path, mode, C_NULL)
        ccall(:uv_fs_req_cleanup, Void, (Ptr{Void},), req)
    finally
        Libc.free(req)
    end
    return ret, ret==0 ? "OK" : Base.struverror(ret)
end

julia> uv_access("/tmp", W_OK)
(0, "OK")

julia> uv_access("/root", W_OK)
(-13, "permission denied")

julia> uv_access("/nonexist", W_OK)
(-2, "no such file or directory")
```

Comment: Julia uses libuv to provide a cross-platform interface to these sorts of functions, and libuv does have an [access-like function](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/fs.html#c.uv_fs_access). Unfortunately its API is much more convoluted, requiring a request object to be passed to it where it stores the result.  Still simpler than doing all the cross platform junk yourself, though.

Comment: @MattB. Thanks! I enhanced my answer (if you have time pls check me). IMHO libuv solution (also if we avoid struverror) will have worse performance on posix than ccalling access directly.

Answer (score 2):

Is the following sufficient:

```
julia> testdir(dirpath) = try (p,i) = mktemp(dirpath) ; rm(p) ; true catch false end
testdir (generic function with 1 method)

julia> testdir("/tmp")
true

julia> testdir("/root")
false
```

Returns `true` if `dirpath` is writable (by creating a temporary file inside a try-catch block). To find the first writable directory in a list, the following can be used:

```
julia> findfirst(testdir, ["/root","/tmp"])
2
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing `apropos("permissions")`:

```
julia> apropos("permissions")
Base.Filesystem.gperm
Base.Filesystem.mkpath
Base.Filesystem.operm
Base.Filesystem.uperm
Base.Filesystem.mkdir
Base.Filesystem.chmod
```

shows a function called `Base.Filesystem.uperm` which seems to do exactly what you want it to:

```
help?> uperm
search: uperm supertype uppercase UpperTriangular isupper unescape_string unsafe_pointer_to_objref

  uperm(file)

  Gets the permissions of the owner of the file as a bitfield of

Value Description       
––––– ––––––––––––––––––
01    Execute Permission
02    Write Permission  
04    Read Permission   

  For allowed arguments, see stat.
```

Unfortunately it seems to be a bit buggy on my (old v7 nightly) build:

```
julia> uperm("/root")
0x07       # Uhhh I hope not?
```

I will update my build and raise a bug if one is not already present.

---

<sub>PS. In case it wasn't clear, I would expect to use this in combination with `isdir` to detect directory permissions specifically</sub>

Comment: uperm return permission for file owner. This is root in this case!

Comment: @Liso ah of course. That makes sense. So I guess if one was interested to find out the permissions of the current julia process, one would have to know the current uid and detect the file's uid using `stat` first ...

Comment: ... and you could have appropriate `gperm` if you are in correspondent `group` etc. And it is a little more complicated because there are also [acl permissions](https://linux.die.net/man/1/setfacl)...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that Dan Getz's answer will work on Windows because the temporary file created cannot be deleted while there is an open handle to it, but this amended version with a call to `close` does work:

```
function isfolderwritable(folder)
    try
        (p,i) = mktemp(folder) 
        close(i)
        rm(p) 
        return(true)
    catch
        return(false)
    end
end
```